# Running Windows Docker Images on Kubernetes Cluster, installed on Windows 10

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-container-registry

I have installed Kubernetes Cluster (minikube) on my Windows 10 machine and seems to be running (ie: I can browse the minikube dashboard, etc).

[image: kubernetes cluster status]

I also have a Windows Image (has an Asp.Net Web API .Net framework 4.6 Application in it) on Azure Container Registry that I would like to pull and deploy to my local Kubernetes Cluster.

I have built the following yaml file to create the Kubernetes deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hubapi
spec:
  containers:
  - name: hubapi
    image: lgmimages.azurecr.io/hubapi/hubapi
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: azurepasswordsecret
```

When I run this command:

```
kubectl create -f hubapi.yaml
```

and I see:

```
pod "hubapi" created
```

Then when I go to the dashboard or get Pod Description I see the following error:

```
kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull image "lgmimages.azurecr.io/hubapi/hubapi": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform
```

I was wondering what I am missing here and is what I am trying to do is even possible?

**Note:** It works when I use this command and pull nginx image from dockerhub:

```
kubectl run kubernetes-nginx --image=nginx:latest --port=80
```

Then I expose this service and I can browse the nginx web page on my local Cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> rpc error: code = Unknown desc = image operating system "windows"
>   cannot be used on this platform

Actually, we install kubernetes on windows 10 **bash on Ubuntu**, in this way, the bash on ubuntu works as a master, base on Linux, we can't run windows docker image on it.

As we know, kubernetes master should be a Linux, you have not other nodes, so we can't run `windows` docker image on it.

For test, you can use `Azure container service` and deploy `kubernetes` with windows nodes, in this way, we can run Windows docker image on the k8s windows nodes.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Thanks, So if I understand your answer, you are saying, what I am trying to do is not possible? Now is this possible on Windows Server 2016? Or is this just a limitation for windows 10?

Comment: @Aram As far as I know, minikube can't run windows docker image now. if you just want to run windows docker, we can install container for windows on your windows.

Comment: this effectively makes kubernetes/minikube useless for devs looking to migrate/develop/test/run their Windows-based enterprise environment in k8's. A shame, since docker compose _does_ support Windows containers without difficulty. Thankfully there's [kompose](https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set up a Kubernetes cluster with nodes running both Windows and Linux, you can give (kubernetes-windows-vagrant)[https://github.com/rjmorse/kubernetes-windows-vagrant] a try. It uses Vagrant to provision the environment.

Comment: Linked GitHub project no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of minikube you can use Docker for Windows with Windows containers mode on (Switch to Windows containers... context menu option from system tray).